# TFS Build Agent $(BuildDefinitionPath) Definition Location

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

Recently our build server ran out of space so one of the things we tried to free up space was to uninstall VS2012 because no one was building against it. Ultimately this did not work so we had to reinstall it.

Now all of our installers are broken because it has changed our $(BuildDefinitionPath) from ..\src.. to ..\Sources..

Does anyone know the Ms file that defines this so we can change it back?

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? What build process template?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this **Working Directory**? You can find it in  Team Foundation Server Administration Console → XAML Build Configuration → Agent xx（the one you are using）→ Properties→Working Directory

[Screenshot for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiSKs.png)